# How to run a script every time a song is about to be over?

Tags: bash, scripts, rhythmbox, dbus, mpris

My intention is to notify-send a message if an unrated song is about to come to end. I am using Rhythmbox with the MPRIS plugin and I found following scripts :

```
#Get position
gdbus call \
 --session \
 --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox \
 --object-path /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
 --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
     org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player Position

#Get metadata such as song length and user song rating
gdbus call \
 --session \
 --dest org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox \
 --object-path /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 \
 --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
     org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player Metadata
```

Output : `(<int64 77000000>,)` (in microseconds) for the first one, and for the second one : `(<{'mpris:trackid': <'/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2/Track/4782'>, 'xesam:url': <'file:///path-to-the-mp4-file'>, 'xesam:title': <'Song title'>, 'xesam:artist': <['Artist name']>, 'xesam:album': <'Album name'>, 'xesam:genre': <['Genre name']>, 'xesam:audioBitrate': <214016>, 'xesam:contentCreated': <'2017-01-01T00:00:00Z'>, 'xesam:lastUsed': <'2017-09-12T13:41:52Z'>, 'mpris:length': <int64 189000000>, 'xesam:trackNumber': <15>, 'xesam:useCount': <6>, 'xesam:userRating': <0.80000000000000004>, 'mpris:artUrl': <'file:///path-to-an-image-i-guess'>}>,)` ('mpris:length' is what matters)

But I don't know how to use the results, espetially how to parse them to check there are less than 10 seconds left (**I need the remaining time as int value and don't know how to achieve it in a script...**).

There over, I am not sure how to implement that. I was thinking about a .sh file, which I would run from a terminal and which would check every few seconds what the playing state is.

Can you give some pieces of advice and/or the begining of a script (which has at least an infinite loop or a recursion -what is the best?- and the remaining time refreshed in a variable) ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: PS : there is a link to the manual for MPRIS MediaPlayer2 I have used, but I don't think it's pertinent, because we already have everything we need from that website : https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html

Comment: It'll likely be easier using the `python` dbus bindings - maybe you can modify / build on this example? [spotify-parser.py](https://gist.github.com/Jackevansevo/526311958c14c763bea205d66a4070d0)

Comment: @steeldriver : Oh, nice !! Apart from the fact I've never used Python neither, that seems much easier and I should get around. I fear, I don't know how to call a bash script from a Python script (because I need bash inside the loop). But I will browse for that. Thanks !!

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to shell out  - see [pydbus - Send a desktop notification](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus#send-a-desktop-notification) or [Desktop Notifications in Python with Libnotify](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/desktop-notifications-python-libnotify) for example

Comment: Thank you very much @steeldriver !! I was able to make what I wanted to :) But I effectively called a shell script from inside my python code instead of calling a library. But thank to you I also began to learn some Python :)

Comment: Well done - and thanks for posting your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post here what I finally made, so that if it interests somebody, he could use it. Thank you to @steeldriver.

```
# first : have python-dbus installed
# sudo apt-get install python-dbus

# run like this : python filename.py --notiftwenty --loop


import json
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import dbus


session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
bus_data = ("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox", "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2")
rhythmbox_bus = session_bus.get_object(*bus_data)
interface = dbus.Interface(rhythmbox_bus, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
metadata = interface.Get("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", "Metadata")
position = interface.Get("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", "Position")

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--artist', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--song', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--album', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--position', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--duration', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--remaining', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--loop', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--notiftwenty', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--rating', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--format', default='json')

def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()

    data = dict()

    if args.position:
        data['position'] = str(position)

    if args.duration:
        data['duration'] = str(metadata['mpris:length'])

    if args.remaining:
        data['remaining'] = str(metadata['mpris:length'] - position)

    if args.rating:
        data['rating'] = str(metadata['xesam:userRating'] * 5)

    if args.notiftwenty:
        if metadata['xesam:userRating'] * 5 < 0.5:
            if metadata['mpris:length'] - position == 20000000:
                data['notiftwenty'] = str('true')
                subprocess.check_output(["notify-send",
                                         "Rhythmbox : notez cette piste !",
                                         "Ce morceau n'a actuellement pas de note...",
                                         "--icon=rhythmbox"])
        if args.loop:
            data['loop'] = str('true')
            subprocess.check_output("sleep 1 && python "+ os.path.realpath(__file__) +" --notiftwenty --loop", shell=True)


    if args.artist:
        data['artist'] = str(next(iter(metadata['xesam:albumArtist'])))

    if args.song:
        data['song'] = str(metadata['xesam:title'])

    if args.album:
        data['album'] = str(metadata['xesam:album'])

    sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(data))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```